# Spring Security - Authentication Not Available in Security Context

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security-oauth2

I have an Angular2 SPI talking to a Spring Boot API layer, secured using the OAuth Implicit Grant Flow, and using Auth0 as my IDP.

API layer is Spring Boot 2.1.0.M2, and also using Spring Security 5.1.0.RC1, and Spring Security OAuth2 2.0.5.RELEASE

There's very little configuration on the API side other than a ResourceServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final CustomAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

    @Value("${oauth2.resource.id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}")
    private String jwks;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfiguration(CorsFilter corsFilter, CustomAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter) {
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.accessTokenConverter = accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) throws Exception {
        config.resourceId(resourceId);
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices()).resourceId(resourceId);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() throws Exception {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(jwkTokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore jwkTokenStore() throws Exception {
        return new JwkTokenStore(jwks, accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/secure-endpoint").authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

My CorsFilter looks like this:

```
@Service
public class CorsFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final AllowedOriginsAccessor allowedOriginsAccessor;

    @Autowired
    public CorsFilter(AllowedOriginsAccessor allowedOriginsAccessor) {
        this.allowedOriginsAccessor = allowedOriginsAccessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        String allowedOrigins = allowedOriginsAccessor.getAllowedOrigins();
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, pragma, cache-control, expires");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

And my JwtAccessTokenConverter looks like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

        @Override
        public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> claims) {
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(claims);
        authentication.setDetails(claims);
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

This all works, in that only authenticated requests from the front end are allowed to access `/secure-endpoint` (I've also secured `/secure-endpoint` with `.access("#oauth2.hasScope('examplescope')")` and verified that this is only allowing authenticated requests containing `examplescope` through). The front end is sending a Bearer token as expected.

The issue is that I've added some custom data to the access token, which I need to use in the API layer. I'm trying to extract the custom data in my `secure-endpoint` controller, using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, but while there is a security context, the Authentication object within it is null.

Stepping through the code I can see that the Authentication object exists in the Security Context (and contains the additional data that I'm expecting) while the FilterChainProxy is processing the additional filter chain. It is gone when the original chain is processed (i.e. when `originalChain.doFilter(request, response)` is called in FilterChainProxy.doFilter), and not there at any subsequent point. The SecurityContextImpl object Id doesn't change so it looks like the same context, minus the Authentication object.

**I can't figure out why, where or how the Authentication object is getting cleared, or how to make it stick so it's available to the controller. Any help or direction with this would be gratefully received.**

Relevant log output (and as mentioned, the Authentication object is available and populated as expected until the 3rd log message from the bottom):

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/secure-endpoint'; against '/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /secure-endpoint' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /secure-endpoint' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /secure-endpoint' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@2fe14c40: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@720fbae6
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/secure-endpoint'; against '/secure-endpoint'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(authenticated)]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@2fe14c40: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@110090b7, returned: 1
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secure-endpoint?orderByLastModifiedAsc=false reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2d219451
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: I am really afraid where you are setting up SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( your user details); are you able to call /secure-endpoint controller method, I mean request is going there??

Comment: @kj007 Yes, I am able to call the /secure-endpoint controller method. It looks like `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication` is getting called by the Spring Security framework at (or around) when the CustomAccessTokenConverter is called (I also tried setting it explicitly there but it made no difference). Either way, I can see the Authentication object in the security context right up until the FilterChainProxy logs that it has 'reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain'